# Create a repository tree on my server working with GIT

Tags: windows, git, server

I could not find what I was looking for by searching with google because I can't figure any keywords that would lead me to an answer.

I started with GIT recently, I use my own server, not the online one : you need to pay to be private. Following this tutorial :

https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-CopSSH

I used this command :

```
git init --bare
```

Everything works just fine, for one project. But i have hundred projects... categorised in 3 section : Web,Desktop, Others.

So i'm currently thinking of :

1. Making myself all the folder tree on the server and repeat the above command inside every single final folder. I know this will work, since it work for one project, but sure will be long.
2. Try to git in my whole folder tree at once... I assume this will fail since there is too much files, probably going to be heavy and I don't know how git will understand what I want to do anyway, I think it will cause push problems.
3. Search for some built-in GIT command that divide the repository to make a folder tree like to one I have localy.

I'm sure someone did this before, I don't want to begin something and later realize it could have been much simpler...

What is the common GIT way to start up when you already have a lot of projects ?

Comment: "you need to pay to be private" - with GitHub, yes. But there are others that offer free private repositories. There are also software you can get that does (some of) what GitHub and others do to have visual navigation to your server. [Git on the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server).

Comment: @crashmstr Like tortoise git, but ... wait, can one of the visual navigaters build all the folder tree for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a single git repository for hundreds of projects would make collaboration effort very difficult, as the commit logs would be aggregated for all project. I would not recommend this.

Assuming you have a collection of projects (P1, P2,..) under MyGitRepo you could automate the process.

```
MyGitRepo
|..P1
|..P2
|..
\..PN
```

You can run the command `git init --bare` in each of the project as follows from Powershell

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyGitRepo -Directory -Depth 0 | Foreach {echo $_.fullname; cd $_.fullname; git init --bare}`

- `Get-ChildItem` - List Items

  - `-Path` - Where to search
  - `-Directory` - Return only directory
  - `-Depth` - return only sub-folders and don't recurse
- Redirect output to `Foreach`

  - `echo` the subfolder
  - `cd` - change directory/enter directory
  - `git ...` - execute command in directory

Incase you have a folder structure as you mentioned

```
MyGitRepo
|..Web
   |..W1
   \..W2
|..Desktop
   \..D1
|..
\..Others
   \..O1
```

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyGitRepo\*\* | Foreach {echo $_.fullname; cd $_.fullname; git init --bare}`

Comment: You mean i could automatise the process of creating folders and initing GIT by using power shell ?

Comment: Yes, automation is one possibility if you projects are grouped and structured in a easy and structured manner.

Comment: Although i'm not a power shell expert, i admit this looks like a very professionnal way to accomplish the task, i'll have a power shell expert do this for me then. Thanks a lot